# Storing Functions in Dictionary [Python]

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, dictionary, data-structures

I'm currently building an application where I need to iterate over a series of steps that do largely the same thing, save a very small amount of code (~15 lines).  The number of steps will vary depending on how the project is configured, so it seems kind of silly for me to create a separate function for each potential instance.

In JavaScript, I would do something like this:

```
var switches = [true, true, false, true];

var holder = {
    0: function() { /* do step0 */ }
    1: function() { /* do step1 */ }
    2: function() { /* do step2 */ }
    3: function() { /* do step3 */ }
    // ...etc...
}

for (var i = 0; i < switches.length; i++)
    if (switches[i])
        holder[i]();
```

Is there a way to do something similar to this in python?  The only thing I can think of is something like this:

```
switches = [True, True, False, True]

class Holder(object):
    @staticmethod
    def do_0():
        # do step0

    @staticmethod
    def do_1():
        # do step 1

    # ...etc...

    def __repr__(self):
        return [self.do_0, self.do_1, ...]

for action in Holder:
    action()
```

This just seems terribly inefficient if I have any significant number of steps.  Is there any better way to go about this?

Comment: A decorator may be more in line with what you want

Comment: What would be the best way to go about doing this?  If I define all of the functions with the same decorator, is there any easy way to loop through them without creating a list to loop through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there isn't a way to do this in Python, a design decision made intentionally since it was dismissed as un-Pythonic.  Oh well, it looks like I'm stuck defining the methods and then manually adding them to a list to iterate through.

Source: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/99245

Answer (score 3):

You can do this as follows:

```
# define your functions
def fun1():
    print("fun1")

def fun2():
    print("fun2")

def fun3():
    print("fun3")


switches = [True, False, True];

# put them in a list (list makes more sense than dict based on your example)
func_list = [fun1, fun2, fun3]

# iterate over switches and corresponding functions, and execute 
# functions when s is True    
for s,f in zip(switches, func_list):
    if s: f()
```

This is one way only. There are many others. e.g. using lambdas, dict as you wanted, etc.

To use lambdas if your functions are one line only, you can do:

```
func_list = [lambda: print("lambda1"), 
             lambda: print("lambda2"), 
             lambda: print("lambda1")]
```

Comment: Your code definitely works, but I'm trying to avoid defining a bunch of functions outside of the dictionary scope though.  I could just use the code I already have otherwise.

Unfortunately the code I'm working with is quite a bit more complicated than the example, and I couldn't really define a bunch of functions without quickly making the code unreadable.

Comment: I added lambdas example. But you cant put everything into lambda's though.

Comment: Python does not have anonymous functions like JS. Yes, there are [```lambda```](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)s, but they are restricted to a single expression.

Comment: Yeah, lambdas would be great if they were a little less limited.  Unfortunately I need ~15 lines for some of the more complicated functions.

Comment: @RobertIngrum So you need to make them separate. You can  make a module with these function, or a class as you did.

Comment: @pzp1997 Do you know if there's any equivalent to closures in Python?  Unfortunately I'm trying to move from PHP to python and this seems pretty limiting.

Comment: There are closures in Python (see this: http://blaag.haard.se/Python-Closures-and-Decorators--Pt--1/). I would also lookup decorators, as they are very related to closures.

Answer (score 1):

```
- Your functions don't need to be enveloped in a utility class.
- I don not see how the two blocks of code differ in efficiency.
- You can use enumerate and lambdas to simplify your code.
```

Simplified Code

```
d = {0: lambda: 'Performing Step 0',
     1: lambda: 'Performing Step 1',
     2: lambda: 'Performing Step 2',
     3: lambda: 'Performing Step 3',
     4: lambda: 'Performing Step 4'}

for index, switch in enumerate([1, 0, 1, 1, 0]):
    if switch == 1: d[index]()
```

Comment: The example I provided is greatly simplified.  In my actual sample, the Holder class is actually just a helper class to hold all of the settings for my step processor.  I also looked into using lambdas at first, but it looks like they can't be too complicated (i.e. they won't work for 15 lines of code).

Answer (score -1):

I typically go about this like the following. 
I like this approach, because it adds a minimum of typing overhead to the code, and if you write an additional method later on, nothing needs to be modified elsewhere in the file.

```
def steptest0():
    code
def steptest1():
    code
def steptest2():
    code

...

tests = filter(lambda x: x.startswith('steptest'),
               dir())
for t in tests: eval(t + '()')
```

Every method is already put into a dictionary automatically in Python, and `dir()` lets us access that.

Disclaimer. There are multiple alarm bells starting to go off in the head of the average pedestrian zealot at the sight of "eval" and some may even have seizures. Let them guard themselves from eval by using a reflection mechanism instead (which might make it less readable, but still worth it, as they can't be accused of using "eval").